# Bought tokens in a game but the game quit, can I get my money back?

Tags: internet

So there was this small scale online game where I bought some ingame tokens to buy a different sprite. I bought 20$ worth of ingame tokens a month ago and spent most of it on items in the game. The game quit some weeks ago and I still had like 5$ in tokens left, also I wasn't able to use the special sprite for long since the game quit after a week of me buying it.

I'm actually not really worried about the money, I think it was worth it even if I could only use it so shortly. But I was wondering if games can just do that, or if there is some sort of legal way to get unused tokens back(and if you can get money back if you a bought an ingame item and where only able to use it for a short while)

Comment: Were there any terms of service and/or use for the game you have in mind? Whether anything you agreed to speaks to this will heavily influence the answer.

Comment: Does "the game quit" mean it stopped working *for you on your device* or that it was discontinued and no longer available?